# Armadillo n_rows doesn't work

Tags: c++, armadillo

I use armadillo to get matrix but seems it gives me the wrong number about cols and rows.

The first picture I have a 30x30 matrix called `se`. I print the number of rows and columns. Then I put `se` into a function called `Acqui`, and print the rows and columns in that function.

```
//define 'mat se' as a 30 by 30 matrix and give it certain value
printf("%u \n",se.n_rows);
printf("%u \n",se.n_cols);
NextP=Acqui(se,arr_sample,Maxu,SamTraPoi);
```

Then in the `Acqui` function, I do the following:

```
Acqui(mat &se,mat &arr_sample,mat &Maxu,mat &SamTraPoi);
{
    int num=se.n_rows;
    int col=se.n_cols;
    printf("%d \n", num);
    printf("%d \n", col);
    //other program
}
```

I got the following result, columns are 900, not right.

[image: result]

See in `Acqui` I did nothing just use reference to transfer the value. If I change the code in `Acqui` like the following, result will change

```
Acqui(mat &se,mat &arr_sample,mat &Maxu,mat &SamTraPoi)
{
    int num=se.n_rows;
    int col=se.n_cols;
    printf("%llu \n", se.n_rows);
    printf("%llu \n", se.n_cols);
    //other programm
}
```

[image: result]

Now the row becomes an extremely big number. Of course the result is supposed to be four 30.

In fact my program ran successfully several days ago. During these days I install a new software to my Ubuntu and finds it uses up my disk space so I just uninstall it. I did nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

This solves so fast...
In fact I made another modification before I ran above programm which I thought would have no problem.
 When I compile the code before in Make file, I just use g++ instead of linking to c++11 like the following

```
g++ samplecode.cpp -o samplecode -O2 -larmadillo
```

Now because I need use a function in c++11 so I need change the make file to

```
g++ -std=c++11 samplecode.cpp -o samplecode -O2 -larmadillo
```

Then I ran the program the armadillo won't work well. So I have to delete

```
-std=c++11
```

The suprising thing is that the code still works even I add the function needs c++11. The function I need use is erfc(). It should only work when link to c++11. Anyway the problem seems solved